# Input a URL of a video in a textField with button to be fetched from the internet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to dart and flutter. This got me stuck for 3 days already. My goal is to have a textfield and a button whereas the user can input a url of the video and it loads in the app.  Hope you can help me. BTW, I already have a default url so a video is already shown so the purpose of the textfield and button is for the user to change. This is what I did right now.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //MEDIA_URL is already declared
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(MEDIA_URL)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = TextEditingController();
    });
  }

Widget _buildInput() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter the URL"),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => print("pressed"),
            child: Text("load"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can do operation on `_controller` , call `pause` and then reinitialize `_controller` to play another video path
code snippet

```
onPressed: () async {
      await _controller.pause();
      MEDIA_URL = _textEditingController.text;
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(MEDIA_URL);
      await _controller.initialize();
      setState(() {});
      await _controller.play();
    }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String MEDIA_URL =
      'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController.text =
        "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4";

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(MEDIA_URL)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  Widget _buildInput() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter the URL"),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await _controller.pause();
              MEDIA_URL = _textEditingController.text;
              _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(MEDIA_URL);
              await _controller.initialize();
              setState(() {});
              await _controller.play();
            },
            child: Text("load"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: _controller.value.initialized
                    ? AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ),
              _buildInput(),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _controller.value.isPlaying
                    ? _controller.pause()
                    : _controller.play();
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this! This is what I want but the URL should not be static. The user can always put any URL for any video. How can I do this?

Comment: it not static. I use fixed value for demo purpose. you can input any address you need to TextField.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Hello. So I can delete the _textEditingController.text="https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4"; right?

Comment: Yes. you can. it's only for demo. so I do not have to input a lot of string in Emulator.

Comment: Hello. I tried adding your code to mine but nothing works. I wonder why. :(

Comment: I think it's an error to use MEDIA_URL if tits not constant. So I used String mediaURL and it worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the onPressed handler of the RaisedButton, you need to set the URL to _controller, and then call setState to rebuild the UI (and therefore load the video).

Here's how you would do it:

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(()=>MEDIA_URL=_controller.text);
}
```

Also note that `MEDIA_URL` should be `mediaURL` (camel cased) because it is not constant.

Comment: Hi! I have a default url in my app which is why I have MEDIA_URL. How can I do this with the mediaURL?

Comment: Make it var, not final.

Comment: I declared it as String MEDIA_URL so like var mediaURL then equal to my  default URL?